# How to set sublime text that will tell whether the file has changed from WinSCP?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, winscp

I have problem on my sublime text editor that whenever the file was changed in the server while editing it, It didn't tell me that my file was not the updated copy, what configurations should I do in sublime or any solutions that will solve my problem?

Comment: Don't push, be kind to people! Good answers will take their time. But I can say this is not a sublime text related problem. This is a WinSCP problem. Sublime only saves the temporary file locally and WinSCP recognizes the change of the local file and uploads it. So improve your question to get a good answer and maybe add some tags for WinSCP.

Comment: What kind of server are you connecting to? I've had a similar problem where I had to change the mount settings so that Sublime could read the update notification.

Comment: we are working on our own server.